# scala recursive function that returns another function

Tags: scala, recursion, higher-order-functions, currying

I was looking at examples of currying technique in scala and didn't understand how a function can return another function when a function is recursive.

for example I understand this code

```scala
def addOne(x: Int): Int = x => x + 1
def repeater(myFunc: Int => Int, n: Int, x:Int): Int = 
    if(n<=0) x
    else repeater(myFunc, n-1, myFunc(x))
```

above one is ok for me, if I say repeater(addOne, 10, 1) returns 11. Till n equals to zero, I decrease n with 1, and recursion stack starts working bottom to up.

But this one confuses me

```scala
def repeater(myFunc: Int => Int, n:Int): Int => Int = {
   if(n<=0) (x:Int) => x
   else (x: Int) => repeater(myFunc, n-1)(myFunc(x))
}
```

The point that I don't understand here, for example, if I run repeater(addOne, 2) it will look the else part and else part says to return a function, so program returns a function at first, or execute repeater one more time with n-1 (1-1) and return another function?
This else part return how many functions, and what will the call stack look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's unfold the recursion step by step.

`repeater(addOne, 2)` returns new anonymous function

```
(x:Int) => repeater(addOne, 1).apply(addOne(x))
```

Where `repeater(addOne, 1)` returns new anonymous function

```
(x:Int) => repeater(addOne, 0).apply(addOne(x))
```

Where `repeater(addOne, 0)` returns new anonymous function

```
(x:Int) => x
```

Therefore `repeater(addOne, 1)` returns an anonymous function which looks like

```
(y:Int) => {
    ((x: Int) => {
        x
    }).apply(addOne(y))
}
```

And `repeater(addOne, 2)` returns an anonymous function which looks like

```
(z:Int) => {
    ((y: Int) => {
        ((x: Int) => {
            x
        }).apply(addOne(y))
    }).apply(addOne(z))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your clear and brief explanation. Thinking with apply() method is very helpful and made me understand more easily.

Comment: Sure :) But I have to say that both three of your answer are well explained and clear for me.

Answer (score 2):

To make it more understandable I will simplify and desugar some part of your function.

Let's first remove `myFunc` parameter and replace it with `addOne` function directly reducing complexity keeping the main question in focus:

```
def repeater(n:Int): Int => Int = {
   if(n<=0) (x:Int) => x
   else (x: Int) => repeater(n-1)(addOne(x))
}
```

Now let's desugar function literal instantiation code

```
def repeater(n:Int): Int => Int = {
  if(n<=0) new Function1[Int,Int]{ //#1
    override def apply(x: Int): Int = x
  }
  else new Function1[Int,Int]{ //#2
    override def apply(x: Int): Int = repeater(n-1)(addOne(x))
  }
}
```

So now you can see that when you call `reporter(2)` it produces new function `#2` without evaluating it. So at the result you will have something like this:

```
val repeaterFirstIteration: Int => Int = {
  new Function1[Int,Int]{
    override def apply(x: Int): Int = repeater(2-1)(addOne(x))
  }
}
```

or let's sugar it back

```
val repeaterFirstIteration: Int => Int = {
  x => repeater(2-1)(addOne(x))
}
```

so now you have `val` containing function literal that you can call like this `repeaterFirstIteration(...)`

Comment: Thanks, lambda expression like ```(x:Int) => x + 1``` and creating function (class Instance actually) with Function1 are totally same right? (Like in Java and Functional Interfaces.) As far as I understand, scala and java functions are almost same in creation.

Comment: yes. `(x:Int) => x + 1` is just a syntax sugar for creating class instance. As far as I know lambdas in java works the same way.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's clarify that if you ran `repeater(addOne, 3)`, you would only get back a function. You would need to run`repeater(addOne, 3)(SomeOtherInteger)` to get your integer value and the result of your computation. All that the recursion is doing here is constructing a function. `repeater(addOne, 3)` returns a function that takes in an integer and returns an integer. Take the example of `repeater(addOne, 3)`, if we write out the result of the recursion fully, this is what we get

```
{ x => {x => { x => { x => x }(myFunc(x)) }(myFunc(x)) }(myFunc(x))) }
```

It might look a bit confusing but lets break it down.

Lets focus on the innermost part -  `{ x => x }(myFunc(x))`. This can be seperated into two parts, a function and an input to the function. The function is `{ x => x }` and the input to this function is `(myFunc(x))` . In this case, all that the function does is return the input back to the user. Thus if we write `{ x => x }(1)` we will get `1`. So we can replace the whole `{ x => x }(myFunc(x))` with just `myFunc(x)`. What we're left with is

```
  { x => { x => { x => myFunc(x) }(myFunc(x)) }(myFunc(x)) }
```

Lets look at the `{ x => myFunc(x)}(myFunc(x))` term. Here the function part is `{ x => myFunc(x) }`  and the input to this function part is given by `(myFunc(x))`. The function part takes in an integer `x` and applies `myFunc` to that integer. It's essentially the same as applying `myFunc` directly to that integer. In this case, the integer we are applying it to is the input `myFunc(x)` so we can rewrite `{ x => myFunc(x) }(myFunc(x))` as `myFunc(myFunc(x))`. Now  we have

```
   { x => { x => myFunc(myFunc(x)) }(myFunc(x)) }
```

We can apply the same logic used in the previous step to break down the `{ x => myFunc(myFunc(x)) }(myFunc(x))` term. We would get `myFunc(myFunc(myFunc(x)))`. If you continue with this logic, you will see that `repeater` is going to keep composing `myFunc`. For each `n`, it will add one more layer of `myFunc`. The result of this would look like this if `n = 3`

```
   { x  => myFunc(myFunc(myFunc((x))) }
```

Thus for `repeater(addOne, 3)`, we would get

```
{ x => addOne(addOne(addOne(x))) }
```

And `repeater(addOne, 5)` is

```
{ x => addOne(addOne(addOne(addOne(addOne(x))))) }
```

All that `repeater` does it to just constructs this function and return it to the user. You could take this return function of `repeater` and put in a `val` called `f`

```
 val f = { x => addOne(addOne(addOne(x))) } //ie repeater(addOne, 3)
```

`f` takes in an integer input and returns that integer plus 3. We can then get the actual result we want using this

```
 val someIntegerPlus3: Int = f(someInteger)
```